# @Autowired not working on jersey resource

Tags: spring, jersey

`workflowService` is null.  The bean configuration is correct because manual injection works fine in other portions of the application.

Here's my resource:

```
@Path("/workflowProcess")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class WorkflowProcessResource {

    @Autowired
    WorkflowService workflowService;

    @Autowired
    WorkflowProcessService workflowProcessService;

    @GET
    @Path ("/getWorkflowProcesses/{uuid}")
    public Collection<WorkflowProcessEntity> getWorkflows (@PathParam("uuid") String uuid) {
        WorkflowEntity workflowEntity = workflowService.findByUUID(uuid);

        return workflowEntity.getWorkflowProcesses();
    }
}
```

From what I keep finding on Google on sites like http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/, it looks like `ContextLoaderListener` is the key.  But I've already added that to the application context.

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet;
import org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketAddOn;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Starting server...");
        final HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(".", 8181);

        WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("Socket", "/");

        //enable annotation configuration
        ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
        ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "com.production");

        //allow spring to do all of it's stuff
        ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener");

        //add jersey servlet support
        ServletRegistration jerseyServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new SpringServlet());
        jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.production.resource");
        jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters", "com.production.resource.ResponseCorsFilter");
        jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
        jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        jerseyServletRegistration.addMapping("/api/*");
```

Comment: could you provide an example with @InjectParam? In which package is located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need here, I think, is [@InjectParam](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html) instead of `@Autowired`

Comment: thats perfect Ori Dar.

Answer (score 0):

@InjectParam worked fine instead of @Autowired, with a slight change

@InjectParam cannot be applied to the constructor itself hence has to be applied to the arguments to the constructor.

`public OrderService(@InjectParam OrderValidationService service,
                    @InjectParam OrderCampaignService campaignService) {
        this.service = service;
        this.submissionErrorHandler = submissionErrorHandler;
        this.campaignService = campaignService;
    }`