# Are @InjectParam and @Autowired same?

Tags: spring, jersey

Are @InjectParam (com.sun.jersey.api.core.InjectParam) and @Autowired (org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired) same?

In one of the project, I have seen both of these are being used for similar purposes, hence I guess both can do the same job.
I am just wondering if my guess is correct or I am missing some critical catch out there.
I would appreciate if someone can explain the difference and which one to use under what situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was useful for you. If it answers your question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: yes, it does. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [`@InjectParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.19/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/InjectParam.html) and [`@Autowired`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) are used for *dependecy injection purposes*.

According to the documentation, Jersey's [`@InjectParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.19/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/InjectParam.html) is used to annotate fields, methods or parameters that shall be injected with instances obtained from Jersey or registered IoC component provider factories that provide support for Guice, Spring or CDI.

Spring's [`@Autowired`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) is used to perform injections in the Spring Framework and, as far as I know, it won't work in Jersey resources.

Answer (score 0):

From this post [@Autowired not working on jersey resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039024/autowired-not-working-on-jersey-resource) , it seems `@Autowired` does not work with `Jersey` resource in which case we have to use  `@InjectParam` for `Jersey resouce`.